# How can I edit a custom field that I have set to be automatically filled

Tags: opportunity, process-builder

I have created a process builder action that automatically fills the Service End Date of an Opportunity, how can I make setting to make the value in the Service End Date field editable if it's wrong?

Comment: Can you post the process builder screenshot??

Comment: Is the field read only on the Opportunity page layout? or does the user's profile not have Edit FLS on the field?